# Cannot view progressBar created in BaseActivity(parent) in MainActivity(child)?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I am trying to make a single base activity for all the redundant actions. I tried putting the progress bar in BaseActivity and tried extending it in MainActivity, But it is not showing up at all.
My Code

activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseActivity";

    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        progressBar = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Log.i(TAG, "setContentView: Progressbar" + progressBar.getVisibility());

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(visibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_get_data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_data);

        btn_get_data.setOnClickListener(view -> {


       if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: DISABLING PROGRESS BAR");
                showProgressBar(false);
            } else {
                showProgressBar(true);
            }

   }


}
```

There are other things in the app, but they have no connection with the progress bar. And yes I have declared the button and other things properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, you can't display the widget in another activity only you can make changes to it but displaying and using it somewhere else is different. Because progress bar is not in your mainActivity xml so it won't display there.

Comment: @Umair I m seeing this tutorial and its working fine. 
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgY3U84KGBg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
super.setContentView(layoutResID);
```

to

```
super.setContentView(constraintLayout);
```

in `setContentView()` method of the BaseActivity.